# Restrictions for an EU citizen travelling through EU and working along the way?

Tags: europe, work, eu, eu-citizens

I am citizen of a country in the EU, I want to fund my travelling within EU by working in other countries. Would I need a Work Permit to gain employment in another EU country?

I only expect to do temporary work as I go from country to country. Or are there some restrictions?

Comment: Hi Chandough and welcome to travel.SE. Unfortunately expat questions are off topic here, you maybe want to commit [the SE expat proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates/) and soon you will be able to get answers of your questions. 
Btw the answer of your qustions: there are only restrictions for citizens of Bulgaria and Romania for some countries (like Germany and UK), but after 1.1.2014 there will be no restrictions

Comment: @Dirty-flow I initially made a similar comment but we do have work-related questions here (presumably because you can work as backpacker or for a short time to support your travel). Also, restrictions for Croatian citizens will last longer (personally I think that it is especially silly for such a small country but 13 countries have already informed the commission that they will apply restrictions at least until 2015).

Comment: I asked this question for my friend, who wants to fund his travelling by working in other countries.He plans to find temporary work. I do not see how this is "off topic" In fact this question actually helps people who still won't travel because they do not have enough money, working while getting to travel to new places is an option!

Comment: @Chandough: Please put some more effort into expanding it between one line with two sentences. For comparison look at how much effort user Annoyed has put into his answer. It is because your question was so brief that people assumed it was an expat question so clarify a bit on that point and I'm pretty sure it will get reopened.

Comment: Oops sorry I meant to say "... expanding it **beyond** one line with two sentences." My apologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Freedom of movement for workers is one of the fundamental building stones of the EU and EU citizens don't need to get prior authorization to work elsewhere in the EU.

In practice, some countries used to (and perhaps still do) deliver some form of residence “permit” but unlike non-EU citizens, you are entitled to get one (i.e. formally the permit just documents your *pre-existing* treaty rights, it's not up to the authorities of the country to give you one or not). In my experience, it's a formality you complete after starting to work, nothing much happens if you don't get one.

For example in Ireland I showed up a couple of times at the local police station where apparently only one garda knew the procedure and he was never there; his colleagues just told me not to bother. In the Netherlands, I got one from the town administration where I was asked if I want one or not and told it's mostly useful to simplify things like getting welfare benefits if I lost my job, etc. (I don't have personal experience with that but I believe you only qualify for welfare after living several years in the country, you can't go “benefits-shopping” and move to a country just for that).

All of this is not yet true for citizens of Romania, Bulgaria and Croatia who still suffer from restrictions in certain countries for up to 7 years after their country joined the EU under transitory rules and do sometimes need to go through a lot of red tape to get a work permit.

Of course, if you want to practice a regulated profession (starting with lawyers and medical doctors but in some countries the list is really long), you need to get your qualifications recognized. Getting this type of things working as smoothly as possible is a big part of what the EU does but that's unlikely to be an issue for short-term jobs. In many countries, you also need to get a tax/health insurance number that locals would have had since their birth and that employers will require.

In some countries, I suspect working legally would also mean that you need to register as a resident with the local administration irrespective of the time you intend to stay (in Germany, Switzerland, the Netherlands, residents have to officially register any change of address within days of moving – it feels kind of creepy to me but it's very easy to do in practice). So there can still be some red tape involved even if you don't need a permit *per se*.

Furthermore, a small number of defense, health or policy-related positions can be closed to citizens from other EU countries (but certainly not *all* public sector jobs). Info on all this [on the official EU website](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=25&langId=en) is very good.

PS: Immigration is mostly off-topic on this site but then again we do have questions about working in Georgia or Argentina and, if you are a citizen from one of the member states, the EU rules obviously also allow you to work for a short time while traveling around Europe.

Comment: Looks like it's more of a working holiday / work and travel question than an immigration question, so on-topic after all. But the OP has put so little effort into his question that it wasn't apparent.

Comment: As my previous comment has been deleted (why?), I would like t stress again that Switzerland is not member of the EU.

Comment: Moreover, as an EU citizen you don't have to register in the country you are working in. You can be registered in one EU country, but working another one.

Comment: @user3470 And I would like to stress that Kazakhstan is not a member of the EU and you can live and work in the EU without being “registered” anywhere. Yes, this has nothing to do with either the question or my answer but so do your comments…